How to load .dat file to Hive with additional columns?
I want to load .dat(without headers) file to hive external table.
But in hive table there are extra columns like cob_date , region, file_name
which are not present in .dat file.
cob_date will be the date present in feed name like customer_data_20240708.dat
region and file_name can be hard coded.
